# geojson for kuala lumpur boundries

Tags: geojson

I want to find the geojson for kuala lumpur boundries and it cities just like this photo.

[image]

I search alot and didn't find anything for that.

thank you for helping.

I tried [text](https://geojson.io/#map=10.08/3.1481/101.6212/25.6/4) but didn't helped me. I tried alot of other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to obtain your city/district data from online spatial data resources like [Natural Earth Data](https://www.naturalearthdata.com), but it may not be easy to obtain a sub-province level layers from these resources. If you cannot find the data from these online resources, try asking the data from your local government sources or map producing companies.

After obtaining the data (it will be probably in ESRI Shape format) you can convert it to `GeoJSON` using the [ogr2ogr tool](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html).

Sample command to produce the `GeoJSON` output:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON D:\output.json D:\input.shp
```

Another alternative to achieve the conversion is to use [QGIS](https://qgis.org/). Just click the *Layer > Save As...* menu and set the *Format* dropdown as GeoJSON.